# Alertas de sintaxis de CSS en ES

Tags: javascript, css

Se podría hacer una subrutina ES para notificarme por cualquier modo un error de sintaxis en CSS?

Comment: Supongo que sí, pero no sería algo trivial. Que yo sepa, el navegador no lanza ningún error que puedas capturar con JavaScript, tendrías que crear un procesador del lenguaje CSS y no sería precisamente pequeño.

Comment: https://github.com/twolfson/css-validator

Answer (score 3):

Este código tomado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014804/javascript-validate-css sirve para validar CSS:

```
function getDefinedCss(s){
    if(!document.styleSheets) return '';
    if(typeof s== 'string') s= RegExp('\\b'+s+'\\b','i'); // IE capitalizes html selectors 

    var A, S, DS= document.styleSheets, n= DS.length, SA= [];
    while(n){
        S= DS[--n];
        A= (S.rules)? S.rules: S.cssRules;
        for(var i= 0, L= A.length; i<L; i++){
                tem= A[i].selectorText? [A[i].selectorText, A[i].style.cssText]: [A[i]+''];
                if(s.test(tem[0])) SA[SA.length]= tem;
        }
    }
    return SA.join('\n\n');
}

// Ejemplo: getDefinedCss('myclassname')
```